# Did I break sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

So I typed

`sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/bin`

and now when I try to use sudo, it says,

`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

I tried to change the permissions of /usr/bin/sudo using chmod but it says

`chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/bin/sudo': Operation not permitted`

What do I do? I can't use sudo and I don't have sufficient permissions to change the permissions of sudo without using sudo.

Edit: Why the downvote?

Comment: That sound like you have had used -r. Easiest repair will likely be to use live environment and set ownership and setuid bits.

Comment: Yes I did; edited my question. What do you mean live environment?

Comment: Bootable iso from USB or anything else you need to get root privileges to set setuid bit on the executable.

Comment: Do you mean using a USB boot? How do I set ownership and setuid bits after booting from media?

Comment: Possibly USB can contain either instalator or live environment one allows you just to install other one boots into linux instance running from ram.  chmod u+s and chmod g+s will set setuid and setgid bits.

Comment: @Hannu that ain't it he overwritten permissions on /use/bin/sudo the link you provided is about removing oneself from sudo group.

Comment: Ouch, too quick on that. Deleting.

Comment: I booted from a USB. When I changed permissions with sudo I was not asked for the sudo password but there was no error message either (sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set). The shell accepted the command and prompted for the next one.  However, when I restarted my device and booted normally the problem remains...

Comment: Also, in the live environment, I tried using chmod without sudo first, just out of curiosity, and it said insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not know root password, the `su` will not work either.
Now you have tough luck. But it is not lost yet.

Go into installed system and type:

```
% df -k /usr
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       61386772 5754168  52491280  10% /usr
```

Remember and better write down this /dev/sda5. In your case, this device will probably be different, as I have several partitions.

Now boot into live DVD.

Enter terminal as root.

Do a command like:

```
# mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

**CAUTION: INSTEAD OF /dev/sda5 type your device written down from previous step!!!**

Now type:

```
# chmod 4755 /mnt/bin/{sudo,chsh,newgrp,passwd,chfn,gpasswd}
# chmod 6755 /mnt/bin/{at,procmail}
```

In fact, the best may be to just do

```
# chmod 4755 /mnt/bin/sudo
```

and the rest you can do in your installed operating system in normal boot as described above.

Comment: It worked, thank you! In the live environment, I had to use 'sudo -i' to enter the terminal as root but I found that quickly on Google.

Comment: Glad it worked :-)
Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you! And you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting back setuid bit on sudo:

```
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

as root, but setting 777 permissions on /usr/bin is a bad idea, so you may also need to do a:

```
# chmod go-w -R /usr/bin
```

to remove write permissions on your binaries from the world.

There are probably a number of programs which demand setuid bit which I will try to list from my system:

```
   root@myhost:~# find /usr/bin -perm -4000 -ls
       131794    156 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root       157192 Jan 20  2021 /usr/bin/sudo
       131485     44 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root        44528 Jul 27  2018 /usr/bin/chsh
       131175     44 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root        44440 Jul 27  2018 /usr/bin/newgrp
       131359     56 -rwsr-sr-x   1 daemon   daemon      55560 Jul 24  2018 /usr/bin/at
       131488     64 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root        63736 Jul 27  2018 /usr/bin/passwd
       131484     56 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root        54096 Jul 27  2018 /usr/bin/chfn
       131487     84 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root        84016 Jul 27  2018 /usr/bin/gpasswd
       131333     92 -rwsr-sr-x   1 root     mail        93392 Nov 16  2017 /usr/bin/procmail
    root@myhost:~#
```

All of these need a `chmod 4755 /usr/bin/<program>`.

This means:

```
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/chsh
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/newgrp
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/passwd
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/chfn
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/gpasswd
```

Or in bash, for the lazy, in one command:

```
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/{sudo,chsh,newgrp,passwd,chfn,gpasswd}
```

EDIT: Note that /usr/bin/at and /usr/bin/procmail have setgid set also, so
you'll need:

```
# chmod 6755 /usr/bin/at
# chmod 6755 /usr/bin/procmail
```

Hope this helps.

Kind regards,
Marvin

Comment: Well, and now you need to describe how to get a root prompt, on her system.

Comment: Possibly su command is not in /usr/bin, so you can still do a ```su -``` and type root password if you know that one.

Comment: I typed su - and entered the sudo password but it says 'Authentication failure'. I'm not sure if the sudo password is the same as the su password? I'm the only user of my system and when I set up Ubuntu I was not asked for a separate root password (meaning the sudo password, root password, and the password for my user login should all be the same...)

Comment: No, ```su``` password must be the root user password, while for ```sudo``` you type user's login password. If you do not know the root password, then you will have to use a live CD or DVD, mount the device manually and change permissions. On the mounted directory, i.e. ```chmod 4755 /mnt/usr/bin/sudo```

Comment: I tried a live environment, please see the comments under the question itself (not under this answer). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I will extend the answer for it cannot fit here ...

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-find-out-root-password-for-installing-software. I did not separately add a root password after installing Ubuntu so shouldn't it just be the same as my user login password? As I mentioned, I am the only user of my system (and the first user created when I installed the OS).